# Yii2 как повторно использовать действия контроллера?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть два идентичных модуля, различия только в том, что данные берутся из разных таблиц.
Как во втором модуле использовать контроллеры модели и виды из первого, чтобы данные брались из другой таблицы?

То есть метод search в действии actionView должен брать данные из другой таблицы

```
$searchModel = new ItemsSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search($params);
```

Comment: Модуль на то и модуль, что должен быть независим ни от чего, даже от других. Поэтому не надо из другого что-то брать. Надо не боятся дублей, и делать всё независимо

Comment: А если предполагается, что эти два модуля **всегда будут вместе**, то тогда, как и логично, сделать что-то общее для них обоих и их наследовать от общего... но опять же, лезть из одного модуля в другой - плохая затея

Comment: *"То есть метод search"* --- так мод**У**ль или мод**Е**ль ?

Comment: так как эти модули всегда должны быть вместе, вы правы на счет того что лучше в одном модуле всё сделать.. метод search находится в МОДЕЛИ, а модель привязана к конкретной таблице.

Comment: Можно использовать контейнер внедрения зависимостей и подменять модель перед использованием.